# How to create a WIndows bootable USB from ISO on Linux Mint Rebecca

Tags: windows-7, linux, usb, linux-mint, iso-image

Searched, all the results that came up were opposite of what I wanted.

I downloaded a Windows 7 (64-bit Home Premium) ISO from digitalrivercontent.net, I have a windows key. How do I burn the ISO to a USB drive and make it bootable from a Linux Mint PC?

Copying the files directly doesn't work, neither does unetbootin. I tried to run Windows utilities that would create the USB (under WINE), but that doesn't work either.

I tried WinUSB, but it just gets stuck on the Formatting device screen.
Formatting it as NTFS first doesn't help either. It gives the following error:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5Ub6.png]

Comment: You didn't say why **unetbootin** didn't work. Maybe you should try [Rufus](http://bootableusb.net/install-windows-ubuntu-usb-drive-using-rufus/) instead. I have used both successfully.

Comment: Unetbootin doesn't work for non-linux OS's. It uses Linux's FAT32 filesystem instead of Window's required NTFS.

Comment: OK. I used the Windows version, which happily created a Linux boot disc, but I've not tried vice versa. I thought there was a Linux version of Rufus, but I can't now find it. However [this link](http://bootableusb.net/create-windows-7-bootable-usb-using-ubuntu/) seems relevant: except possibly for `gparted`, which you don't need to use, as you have obviously got other ways to format as NTFS, you should be able to do the other commands. The linux 494 version is on [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unetbootin/files/UNetbootin/494/) and it seems to work as described.

Comment: Tried that too, I get the same result. I boot in, but when I hit the default button, nothing happens, other than the screen reloading (the automatic boot timer resets to 10s).
Also, Rufus doesn't work for me under WINE.
It seems like I may have to just get a DVD and attempt burning the ISO.

Comment: Two final thoughts: (1) get a friend or colleague with Windows to help: MS provide their own conversion [tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/windows-usb-dvd-download-tool), or try the Windows version of unetbootin; (2) [Hiren's BootCD](http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd) provides a Windows environment may be able to run one of these tools (of course, this depends on your getting _that_ on to a memory stick - _Catch 22_ perhaps?).

Comment: Yeah, got a colleague to do it. Thanks, anyway.